# Why xmlDocument.Select return zero count

Tags: c#, winforms, xmldocument

i am trying to  access a node for xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinkAnalysis>
  <ImgInfo>
    <Number>xyz</Number>
    <ImgPath>D:\Projects\VERBALinks\VERBALinks\bin\Debug\LA_img\xyz.png</ImgPath>
  </ImgInfo>
</LinkAnalysis>
```

using following code

```
 var nodes = doc.SelectNodes(String.Format("/LinkAnalysis/ImgInfo[@Number=\"{0}\"]", "xyz"));
```

But it returns me zero count. Why??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<Number>` is an element, not an attribute, so your XPath expression is wrong.

Try:

```
String.Format("/LinkAnalysis/ImgInfo[Number/text()='{0}']", "xyz")
```